# My Game Loads Before Transition is Finished Unity How Do I Fix This?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/03ad062b9a2a6233d4c91912a91ef23e) < when ever I click my replay button and when the transition is about to start it loads the game before the transition even ends you can see the game being loaded and causes this snappy effect that I'm not sure why is there anyway i could fix this?

my code even though I have a yield that waits for the aimation to finish it doesn't wait at all it only delays when the animation will show and plays the game.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class replayscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject replaybutton;
    public Animator transitionERR;
    public float transitiontime = 19f;
    GameObject replay;
    public float timeRR = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
        replay.SetActive(false);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("replaybutton")){
            Debug.Log("candice");
            StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(1));
            replay.SetActive(true);
        }
    }


    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        //play animation
        transitionERR.SetTrigger("start");


            //wait for the animaton
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        //load the scene

         SceneManager.LoadScene(1);

    }

    }
```

Comment: I tried addingbit and still the same

Comment: I even added 20 the transition  will play the same time as my restart

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is `c#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding the  `transitionERR.SetTrigger("start");` before using the `StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(1));`

You could make an event for the animation end and then put your load scene code in there.
Something like:

```
//
            public UnityAnimationEvent OnAnimationComplete;
            public AnimationClip clip;
//
            AnimationEvent animationEndEvent = new AnimationEvent();
            animationEndEvent.time = clip.length;
            animationEndEvent.functionName = "AnimationCompleteHandler";
            animationEndEvent.stringParameter = clip.name;
            clip.AddEvent(animationEndEvent);
//
public void AnimationCompleteHandler(string name)
    {
        OnAnimationComplete?.Invoke(ChangeSceneMethodName);
    }
```

Also if you plan on using a coroutine to get a animation duration you could use `WaitForSeconds(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length+anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime);`